# Code UI Test Builder not working after update Visual Studio to update 4

Tags: visual-studio-2013

I update Visual Studio to update 4 and when i try to use Code UI Test Builder. Recording is fine but when i tried to generate code, it gets stuck on "Generating Code..." message. I let it run for a while but never finish generating code.

Is this a known issue?

Is there a work around?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Visual Studio Update 5 fixed it.